# Set iframe content width

Tags: html, iframe

I have a 1500px wide viewport. I'm using an iframe to display a preview of another website. The iframe width is 50% of my window (Therefore 750px).

Unfortunately, the other website CSS is configured so that under 800px, it shall be displayed as on a mobile viewport.

How can I keep my iframe being 50% of my screen, but displaying the content as if it was 1500px wide ?

Comment: Use `width: 50%; transform: scale(calc(750 / 800));`

Comment: @connexo where ? in the iframe styling ?